# Beer Sizes in Spain and Portugal

Tags: glassware, classification

Beer sizes in spain are aptly explained in http://matadornetwork.com/nights/order-beer-spain/ (copa, cana, tanque, jarra, etc.)

In portugal, similar sizes appear but I've only heard of `imperial` and `caneca`.

**Are there other sizes of beer in Portugal/Spain?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have nice words to ask in Spain for a shooter beer, but I can add somes:

big quantity (1L or more)

```
mini
cachi
```

regular size (200cl-500cl)

```
tubo
```

little quantities:

```
cañita  
corto
chato  (used for beer but usually of wine)
zurito (basque country and andalucia but extendind all over Spain)
```

but we have also words to name beer bottles depending the size:

20cl bottle:

```
botellin
quinto    (in north regions like Catalunya)
```

33cl bottle:

```
tercio
mediana   (in north regions like Catalunya)
```

1 l  bottle:

```
litro
litrona
xibi *
```

`*` from [Xibeca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xibeca), Damm big bottles

Answer (score 0):

In Madeira and possibly also Portugal, the most popular size is a balau, ie a baloon at 30ml.
Large glasses can quickly get warm. There is also a fino at 20cl.